# Getting error while deploying with web3 version 1 using async wait

Tags: contract-deployment, web3js-v1.x

I am trying to deploy my code to Infura network i compiled and i got no errors  but now when i am trying to deploy i am getting error

```
const HDWalletProvider =  require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');

const   Web3 =  require('web3');

const { interface , bytecode } = require('./compile');

//const inter = require('./compile');


const provider =  new HDWalletProvider(
  'timber belt sem',  // my memonic
  'https://rinkeby'   // my test network 
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async() => {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  console.log("Atemting to deploy the contracts from " , accounts[0]);

   const result  = await new  web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
   .deploy({ data: bytecode , arguments:['','']})
   .send({ gas:'1000000' ,from : accounts[0]});

   console.log("your contract is deployed to", result.options.addres);


};

deploy()
```

Getting following error

```
 Atemting to deploy the contracts from  1.1112838411420756e+48
        (node:28660) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Provided address "1.1112838411420756e+48" is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or its an indrect IBAN address which can't be converted.
            at Object.inputAddressFormatter (/home/mdvenkatesh/Desktop/etherium solidity programes/hotelbooking/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/formatters.js:409:11)
            at Contract.getOrSetDefaultOptions [as _getOrSetDefaultOptions

    ]
```

My solidity code

pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

```
contract hoteltranscation  {

    struct hotel{
        string HotelName;
        uint256 BookingNumber;
    }

    hotel[] HotelBookings;

    function HotelBooking(string _HotelName, uint256 _BookingNumber) public   {
        HotelBookings.push(hotel (_HotelName, _BookingNumber));
    }

    function GetHotelBooking(uint _num) public view returns(string, uint256) {
        return (HotelBookings[_num].HotelName, HotelBookings[_num].BookingNumber);
    }
}
```

deploy code correctly for my previous code but now i can't use   it

dependeces

```
 mocha ganache-cli web3@1.0.0-beta.26
```

Comment: It looks like your `accounts[0]` data is getting mangled or otherwise converted to an integer (hence the 1.1112838411420756e+48). The thing is, it doesn't appear to be caused by anything in your code--unless this isn't your full code. Could you `console.log()` the `accounts` object just before the "attempting to deploy" log line and post back with the output?

Comment: ok i will update once it is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that deploy parameters are right, `from`, `data` parameters should be strings in hex format with `0x` prefix.

```
let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi)));

await contract.deploy({data: '0x' + bin, arguments: contractArgs})
    .send({gas: 2310334, from: accounts[0]});
```

Comment: i have changed the gas it successfully deployed    could you help with two things 1) how to leave gas default without specific   2) after deploying it is showing your contract is deployed to undefined

Answer (score 1):

which version of `truffle-hdwallet-provider` are you using? If you are using the new version of web3, you need a different version of the provider. This is what I have in my `package.json` for one of my projects using new web3:

`"truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.0-web3one.0"`

Comment: Thanks for replay 

But it failed i got a diffrent error  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201353/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-error-the-contract-code-couldnt-be-stored-p